# On Mac Sierra, I can't get Java EE first cup tutorial to load the web page

Tags: java, macos-sierra

I installed glass fish 4.1.1 and I'm attempting to run the java EE first cup tutorial on a Mac running Sierra.  The duke-age project compiles and runs but it does not load a web page as per the documentation. The first cup-war project also compiles and runs.  It also doesn't load a web page.  Java is enabled in the browser.  I don't see any error messages in the GlassFish server window, or in the run window on my NetBeans IDE.  Any ideas?

Comment: "Does not load a web page" - and this means?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).